# Moving 2+ storyboard's children to one Storyboard after Animation names registered to target Frameworkelements

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a storyboard class wrapper to combine storyboards. inst3.join(inst1, isnt2)
First I prepare() two framework elements each in their own wrapper instance, then use join() in a fresh instance. then when i play() the combined instance, i reregister it's new storyboard for the targets.
For some reason the first target I add tries to find registered names that should be on the second target. Im getting

'rotateTogglebutton' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.'

I have a Button then a Togglebutton.

I dont understand how Button is looking for animationnames that have been assigned only to Togglebutton by Storyboard.SetTargetName (which really doesnt know about the Storyboard the animations are in)

I believe in xaml the result should look like

```
<Storyboard x:Key ="combined">
       <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="rotateButton"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
      From="1" To="11" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
      />
       <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTogglebutton"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
      From="1" To="22" Duration="0:0:0.1" 
      />
</Storyboard>
```

(

```
  private void Prepare(FrameworkElement target) //(robot1 then robot2)
  {

        targets.Clear();

        _storyboard = new Storyboard();

        target.Resources.Remove("transformsb");
        target.Resources.Add("transformsb", _storyboard);


        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();

        RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();


        target.RenderTransform = tg;// new RotateTransform(50); transofrm

        tg.Children.Add(rotate);
    
        targets.Add(target);


        NameScope.SetNameScope(target, new NameScope());

        var regname = "rotate" + target.Name;

        target.RegisterName(regname, rotate);
     

        var RotateAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(RotateAnim, regname);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(RotateAnim, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));

        _storyboard.Children.Add(RotateAnim);


        ...
}


    public void Join(AurumStoryboard[] sbs)
    {
        foreach (AurumStoryboard asb in sbs)
        {
            _storyboard.Children.AddRange(asb._storyboard.Children);
            targets.AddRange(asb.targets);



        }


    }


        public void Play(bool reversed = false)
        {
        //joined storyboard has to be added to target elements resources
        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            target.Resources.Remove("transformsb");
            target.Resources.Add("transformsb", _storyboard);
         
        }
        _storyboard.Begin();
        ...

}
```

Comment: Just for the right overview, i used a bad naming in the example so you couldnt tell the storyboard instance from the static Storyboard class.. fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
    Ok solved it, I have registered everything on the parent window. 

    var ns = NameScope.GetNameScope(target.FindParent<Window>());
        if (ns == null)
        {
            NameScope.SetNameScope(target.FindParent<Window>(), new NameScope());
        }


        var exists = target.FindParent<Window>().FindName("rotate" + target.Name);
        if (exists != null)
        {
            target.FindParent<Window>().UnregisterName("rotate" + target.Name);
        }
        target.FindParent<Window>().RegisterName("rotate" + target.Name, rotate);
```